# Tables of class numbers of cyclotomic fields

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory, cyclotomic-fields

Does anyone have a table of the class numbers ($h_n$) of cyclotomic fields (upto say, n = 250-300 for $\mathbb Q(\mu_n)$)?

I can find tables for the relative class number ($h_n^-$) in various places like Washington's book and I can also find tables for class numbers of $\mathbb Q(\zeta_p)$ for $p$ prime. However, I am really interested in the class numbers for $n$ composite and I don't seem to be able to locate any. Probably someone with better googling skills could locate it...

Sage also takes too long to calculate class numbers after a point.

Alternatively, are there any results known on what $h_n^+ = h_n/h_n^-$ can be for the range $n \leq 300$?

I would appreciate it if the table were in a format where I could easily copy paste from.

Comment: No one knows how to compute these class numbers. Washington's book has tables containing what are believed to be plus class numbers based on computations by Schoof.

Answer (score 2):

See

*Class numbers of real cyclotomic fields of composite conductor* by John Miller
https://doi.org/10.1112/S1461157014000382

and

*Norm relations and computational problems in number fields*
by Jean-François Biasse, Claus Fieker, Tommy Hofmann, Aurel Page
https://doi.org/10.1112/jlms.12563

for partial progress on the problem of determining $h_n^+$ for $n$ `large' and composite.